# Unexpected PaxHeader inside gzip file created using gulp-gzip

Tags: gulp, gzip, tar

I am using a gulp task to gzip my source files and set into a dist folder. I am able to successfully generate xyz.tar.gz file, but when I try to see the files in it using a 7zip on windows 7, I see a lot of files named "PaxHeader" each of different size.

Tried searching on internet, but results were more of gzip related and unable to understand. Can someone let me know why this is happening? Is it a gzip related issue or a wrong configuration of gulp-gzip? TIA

[image: Screenshot]